# Javascript No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, api, request, cors

I have a problem with this function:

```
function sound1() {

  const apiUrl = "https://speechgen.io/index.php?r=api/text";

  const data = {
    token: "key",
    email: "email",
    voice: "voice",
    text: "text"
  };

  $.ajax({
    url: apiUrl,
    method: "POST",
    data: data,
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log("Error:", errorThrown);
    }
  });
}
```

The error is "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I've managed to fix this problem with a chrome extension but I'd like to put the solution directly in the code. I don't know how to add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Comment: Which framework do you use for the backend? You need to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin on the server

Comment: I'm a beginner, I don't use a framework just javascript in HTML code

Comment: This needs to fix in the backend rather than frontend code. In your server, It need to whitelist your frontend url.

Comment: I am not familiar with the terms frontend and backend. What is frontend code and backend code but also frontend url in my case

Comment: Backend is the server and frontend is the client, e.g. the browser. You can't solve this in browser code. A browser extension in this case isn't what I mean with browser code. The CORS policy is a security feature in browsers.

Comment: So if I understand correctly I can't do anything I have to contact the API server?

Answer (score 0):

This error mostly comes when you try access an API wherein your client try to access a resource using an API with different domain or the resource server is not configured to accept request from different domain (includes subdomains as well).
In your case https://speechgen.io is the domain which you are trying to access and since I guess your client domain server id different and is not whitelisted it is throwing the error.
You can see in the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors) error documentation this might help.
Also there are other ways like

1. Use of reverse proxy server or WSGI servers like Apache or Nginx where you can configure for OPTIONS method support using proxy request
2. Adding support for OPTIONS method in your API project

Since I am not sure about the backend implementation in your case this is the best I can do.

Comment: Would another solution be to contact the server to solve the problem?